# Disable tablesorter in one column in a table in jquery tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using `jquery-tablesorter` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
        // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
        var sorting = [[0,0],[2,0]];    
        // sort on the first column 
        $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
        // return false to stop default link action 
        return false; 

});
```

There are total 5 columns in my table. How can I disable sorting in the last column?

Comment: read the docs http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this and it works:

```
// Disable sorting in 5th column 
$("table thead th:eq(4)").data("sorter", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers:{
            4: { //last column
                   sorter: false;
            }
        }
    });
        // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
        var sorting = [[0,0],[2,0]];    
        // sort on the first column 
        $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
        // return false to stop default link action 
        return false; 

});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
[Break On This Error]  

sorter: false;}

/list_session/ (line 56, col 32)

Comment: @user2032220 i just edited...check again. I missed a `}` before.

Comment: @user2032220 sorry I missed one more `}`

Comment: @stackErr: `headers:{ 4: { sorter: false;} }`. there are five columns and count starts at zero...